# Klein-Gordon-equation invariant under inversion in space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

In nonlinear physics it's a common technique to investigate an equation's symmetries before solving it.
Because the Klein-Gordon-equation is invariant under inversion in space:

$\left[ \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} - \nabla ^2 + m^2 \right] \phi (x) = 0 $

you would expect the solution to have the same properties.

Since the Klein-Gordon equation describes pseudoscalar mesons, they are of course do not have a parity of 1, but of -1.
Is the misconception that mesons are not truly a single spin zero particle but made up of fermions? 
How can the invariance of the Klein-Gordon equation be interpreted physically?

Answer (score 3):

> In nonlinear physics it's a common technique to investigate an equation's symmetries before solving it.

You do know that Klein-Gordon equation is linear, right?

> Because the Klein-Gordon-equation is invariant under inversion in space, you would expect the solution to have the same properties.

Nope!

The covariance of the equation *does not* imply the invariance of its solutions! Instead it implies that solutions get transformed to (possibly, different) solutions of the same equation.

For example, take a plane wave
$$ f(t,\mathbf{r}) = e^{i \omega t - i \mathbf{p} \mathbf{r}} $$
which is a solution of the original equation for $m = 0$. What will you get by reflecting it? You will get another plane wave
$$ f'(t, \mathbf{r}) = e^{i \omega t + i \mathbf{p} \mathbf{r}}. $$
By the invariance of the Klein-Gordon equation under spatial reflections it is guaranteed that $f'$ is a solution, but it is not at all true that $f=f'$!

As to the second part of your question, please formulate it more precisely.

> Is the misconception that mesons are not truly a single spin zero particle but made up of fermions?

Indeed this is a misconception. However, the spin-0 description is quite accurate in most cases.

> How can the invariance of the Klein-Gordon equation be interpreted physically?

As I said before, its solutions have to be transformed to another solutions. When we interpret them as elementary particles, the impact of this invariance can be seen as the existence of conserved parity.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know the equation is nonlinear, but I was just confused by this technique of how to approach unknown equations that I learned in nonlinear physics courses.